# How select one specific field AND arrange by specific key results of mysql query with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, rails-activerecord

I need all `name` field of my model Topic, but arrange by specific key, in my case the `id`.

I would like a code like :

```
Topic.all.pluck_and_arrange_by :id, :name
```

result:

```
{ 1 => 'foo', 2 => 'bar', 3 => 'baz' }
```

where foo is the name of Dialog with id 1 ...etc

What way to do that?

Comment: Can the `ids` be irregular?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not worried about the ***sequence*** of the `ids`, the below will do

```
Topic.pluck(:id, :name).to_h #=> { 1 => 'foo', 2 => 'bar', 3 => 'baz' }
```

Comment: good try, but i'm in more particular case. the `name` attribute is in fact a virtual attribute, It use I18n tranlation call. So this method don't work because `name` don't exist in DB. I need to call name like `.map &:name` but in same time I need arrange by id key...